# My Skype contacts are missing. How to retrieve my Skype contacts?

Tags: skype

My Skype contacts are gone after I sign in. How to retrieve my Skype contacts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As contacts information of users are also stored in Skype servers, I recommend that you contact the customer service for assistance.

https://support.skype.com/support_selection